# multiple results with mysql and php in modal of bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to print in the modal the information of the selected user but only the first row is printed in the modal.

I am using PHP with MySQL but it is not working. I don't understand why it prints only the first row.

Please help to resolve my issue.

This is the php code:

> 

```
include ("conex.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE cargo='personal'";
$datos=mysqli_query($conex,$query);

echo "<div class='tables'>";
echo "<h3 class='title1'>Listado de Empleados :</h3>";
echo "<div class='panel-body widget-shadow'>";
echo "<table class='table'>";
echo "<button class='btn btn-success add-prod'>
                         <span class='fa fa-plus'></span>  
                                  Agregar Empleado
                         </button>";

echo "<thead><tr><th>Rut</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th class='action'>Accion</th></thead>";



while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos))
    {   


        echo "<tbody>";
        echo "<tr title='informacion detallada' class='selector-empleado' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#infodetallada'>";
        echo "<td>".$fila["rut"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila["nombre"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$fila["apellido"]."</td>";
        echo "<td class='buttons-admin'><button title='modificar empleado' class='btn btn-primary btn-admin1'><span class='fa fa-refresh'></span></button>
        <button  onClick='window.location=\"eliminarempleado.php?rut=".$fila["rut"]."\";'/ title='eliminar empleado' class='btn btn-danger btn-admin2'>
        <span class='fa fa-times'></span></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";





    echo "<div class='modal fade' id='infodetallada' role='dialog'>";
    echo  "<div class='modal-dialog'>";

    echo  "<div class='modal-content'>";
    echo  "<div class='modal-header'>";
    echo   "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>";
    echo    "<h4 class='modal-title'>Informacion detallada :</h4>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
    echo  "<b>Rut : </b>" .$fila["rut"]."<br>";
    echo  "<b>Nombre : </b>" .$fila["nombre"]."<br>";
    echo  "<b>Apellido : </b>" .$fila["apellido"]."<br>";
    echo  "<b>Cargo : </b>" .$fila["cargo"]."<br>";
    echo  "<b>Correo : </b>" .$fila["correo"]."<br>";
    echo  "<b>Contraseña : </b> ************";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
    echo "<button title='modificar empleado' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='fa fa-refresh'></span> Modificar</button>";
    echo "<button onClick='window.location=\"eliminarempleado.php?rut=".$fila["rut"]."\";'/ title='eliminar' class='btn btn-danger'><span class='fa fa-times'></span> Eliminar </button>";
    echo  "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";




    }

        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";

    mysqli_close($conex);
```

Comment: How do you say that it prints only the first row. Have you checked in firebug or it shows same content for all the modals? How do you open the modals? is there a button click event for each modal?

Comment: Shows the same content in all modal, only the first row of the table, the modal is opened when pressing on the row with the selector-empleado class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make couple of minor changes.

Append some unique id to the data-target attribute in  the clickable element, so that it is unique for each record

```
<tr title='informacion detallada' class='selector-empleado' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#infodetallada".$fila['rut']."'>
```

Append same unique id to the id attribute of the modal, so that it is same to the respective clickable element.

```
<div class='modal fade' id='infodetallada".$fila['rut']."' role='dialog'>
```

I assumed that `$fila['rut']` will be unique for each of the records. If it is not so, then you can use some other unique elements.

**Issue:** Each model box should be connected on its own unique ID. It should have unique '`data-target`' in the clickable element & '`id`' in the respective modal.